# How can i update a tkinter window with a new defined variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create two windows with one button in the first one one and one label in the second.
When i press the button the label in the second window should refresh and display the variable plus 1.

I dont want to close the second window and re open it afterwards.
Any ideas how that could be done?

```
import tkinter as tk

text = 1
root = tk.Tk()
root2 = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, bg="green", text=text, fg="blue")
label.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relheight=0.3, relwidth=0.3)

def plus():
    global text
    text = text + 1

    print(text)


button = tk.Button(root2, bg="blue", text="Button", command=plus)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
root2.mainloop()
```

This code should do the basics but the line to refresh the second window is still missing.

Hopefully anyone can tell me how to that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Toplevel()` window instead of using `Tk()` as secondary windows. Tkinter is single threaded so using one `mainloop()` is sufficient for all the windows.

Now as you've asked that you want one button in one window and a label which updates in the second window, and also you can reopen the window without losing any progress if you close the second window.

**Here is my way.**

```
import tkinter as tk

text = 1
root = tk.Tk()
root2 = tk.Toplevel()

label = tk.Label(root2, bg="green", text=text, fg="blue")
label.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relheight=0.3, relwidth=0.3)

def plus():
    global text, root2, label
    if not root2.winfo_exists():  # checks if the window is closed or not
        root2 = tk.Toplevel()
        label = tk.Label(root2, bg="green", text=text, fg="blue")
        label.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relheight=0.3, relwidth=0.3)

    text += 1
    label['text'] = text

button = tk.Button(root, bg="blue", text="Button", command=plus)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Using `IntVar()` to update all the label values. Can use `StringVar()` for sting type:

**Sample**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root2 = tk.Toplevel()

# This is a textvariable IntVar can also use StringVar for sting input
text = tk.IntVar()   
text.set(1)             # Set the initial to 1

# Use 'textvariable' instad of text
label = tk.Label(root2, bg="green", textvariable=text, fg="blue")
label.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relheight=0.3, relwidth=0.3)

label2 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=text)
label2.pack()

def plus():
    global text, root2, label
    if not root2.winfo_exists():  # checks if the window is closed or not
        root2 = tk.Toplevel()
        label = tk.Label(root2, bg="green", textvariable=text, fg="blue")
        label.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relheight=0.3, relwidth=0.3)

    text.set( text.get()+1 )     # incrementing by 1 ( text.get() will return the value )

button = tk.Button(root, bg="blue", text="Button", command=plus)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I hope you may find something useful from my answer.

Comment: thanks too 
but is ther any way how i could do that and not call the label directly?

Comment: _Not call the label directly_.. please elaborate?

Comment: well in your example you directly said for label["text"] = str(text) but i want to do that without that label part i want to say every label witch has the text=text there s text as text

Comment: i want to make it by using a variable not by telling the label directly what it should display

Comment: @python_beginner If you want a label to represent a variable, and change when the variable changes, you'll have to build some kind of repeated task or thread that updates the label text on a regular interval.

Comment: @python_beginner I updated my answer and added more information on how you can use `StringVar` and `IntVar`

Answer (score 0):

You can't run two mainloops in one thread. Your call to `root.mainloop()` blocks until you close the window. Once you close the window, it exits that method and runs `root2.mainloop()` because it's the next line of code.

One root pane can have multiple windows, you don't need to make a `root2`. You want to make two [Toplevel windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm)

Comment: Just mainloop the main window in the end of your code and that's it

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon the answer already given, you should use Toplevel rather than two root windows. 
Also in order to change the text of the label you use `label['text'] = str(text)` to update the value.

```
import tkinter as tk

text = 1
root = tk.Tk()
root2 = tk.Toplevel()

def plus():
    global text
    text = text + 1
    label['text'] = str(text)

label = tk.Label(root, bg="green", text=text, fg="blue")
label.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relheight=0.3, relwidth=0.3)


button = tk.Button(root2, bg="blue", text="Button", command=plus)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: okay thanks alot for the first part but how can i convert the text variable into a string without calling the exact label i want to use the string in ?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand, try this, every time you open a window, toplevel, the label in the new window is increment by 1

```
import tkinter as tk

class Test(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent, count):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent =  parent
        self.count = tk.IntVar()
        self.count.set(count)

        self.title("I'm a new toplevel.")
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.count).pack()
        self.close_me = tk.Button(self, text= "Close me", command = self.on_close_me).pack()
        self.close_parent = tk.Button(self, text= "Close parent", command = self.on_close_parent).pack()

    def on_close_me(self):
        self.destroy()        

    def on_close_parent(self):
        self.parent.on_close()


class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,):

        super().__init__()

        self.master.title("Hello World")

        self.count =0

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1,)

        f = tk.Frame()

        w = tk.Frame()

        tk.Button(w, text="Open", command=self.callback).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)
        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)


    def callback(self):
        self.count +=1
        obj = Test(self,self.count)

    def on_close(self,evt=None):
        self.master.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```